# Number field turned out as text in Excel, SSRS

Tags: excel, reporting-services, report

In my SSRS reports one of the fields is using this expression, where the field is a number field. I want to see blank field if the value is `0`.

```
=IIf(Fields!PERIOD02_VALUE.Value <> 0,Fields!PERIOD02_VALUE.Value ,"")
```

the Excel exported version is having this field considered as text not number.

Is there any other way to do this from SSRS side?

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem. Some cells would be text and others numbers - all with the same formatting string. The resolution is to multiply your cells expression by 1.000 (1 doesn't work!) - this forces SSRS to format the cell as a number. eg; (your expression here) * 1.000

Answer (score 4):

Excel is recognizing this field as text because you are outputting an empty string whenever the field is 0.

You could try this, to output a null value instead of an empty string:

```
=IIf(Fields!PERIOD02_VALUE.Value <> 0,Fields!PERIOD02_VALUE.Value,  Nothing)
```

This isn't guaranteed to work, however, as I seem to remember Excel assumes that the field is the type of whatever is in the first data row.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem in the excel export and solved it with the CLng for integers and CDbl function for decimals.

=CLng(Fields!Qty.Value)

This guarantees that the excel cell will be numeric and is cleaner than Fields!Qty.Value * 1.000

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, I know this is old but worked for me also -- finally a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your IIF statement ends with an empty **string**, "". If you change that to a zero, it will work as expected:

```
=IIf(Fields!PERIOD02_VALUE.Value <> 0,Fields!PERIOD02_VALUE.Value, 0)
```

Instead of...

```
=IIf(Fields!PERIOD02_VALUE.Value <> 0,Fields!PERIOD02_VALUE.Value, "")
```

Answer (score -1):

Below are 3 different solutions for 3 different glitches :

**Value 1**

> 1234
>  blank cell
>  1234

Solution 2

```
=IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!TEST.Value.ToString()), CDBL(IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!TEST.Value.ToString()), Fields!TEST.Value.ToString(), "0")), " ")
```

**Value 2**

> 1234
>  Null
>  345
>  null

Solution 2

```
=IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!TEST.Value.ToString()), CDBL(IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!TEST.Value.ToString()), Fields!TEST.Value.ToString(), "0")), "NULL")
```

**Value 3**

> 1234
>  Null
>  345
>  N/A
>  550
>  TBA
>  440
>  599
>  NOT
>   APPLICABLE

Solution 3

```
=IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!TEST.Value.ToString()), CDBL(IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!TEST.Value.ToString()), Fields!TEST.Value.ToString(), "0")), Fields!TEST.Value.ToString()),
```

Comment: It's not clear how these "Values" answer the question.

Comment: you can assume "Value" AS Column names ,rest are values in columns